# SQL Select Query to PowerShell Help

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, powershell

So....
I have a SQL (MSSQL 2005) query that gathers some data I need to represent or send elsewhere. In this particular case I need to create a CSV from the query, which in PowerShell is pretty simple stuff.

HOWEVER my problem is this. 
How do I run my query (preferably against a remote system/the SQL server) ?
How do I pass the query required parameters? (see PARAM1, PARAM2, PARAM3) ?

Bonus points...
PARAM1 should be a date, format yyyy-mm-dd works.
PARAM2 should be one of three options, OPT1, OPT2, OPT3
PARAM3 should be a string of X number of characters.

PS
Yes using osql.exe occurred to me, but as I was scripting it in batch it dawned on me that... well I don't want to use batch anymore. ;-)

```
Select COL1, COL2 FROM [database].[dbo].[function](PARAM1,PARAM2,PARAM3);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty easy with the [SQL cmdlets in 2.0:](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281847.aspx)

```
$Query = "Select COL1, COL2 FROM [database].[dbo].[function](PARAM1,PARAM2,PARAM3)"
$Results = Invoke-SQLCmd -ServerInstance <server> -Database <DB> -Query $Query
```

Then you can use the column names in your `$Results`, i.e.:

`$Col1 = $Results.COL1`

You can parse your `$Query` for your other parameters too, i.e.:

`$Query = "Select COL1, COL2 FROM [database].[dbo].[function](" + $Param1 + "," + $Param2 + "," + $Param3 + ")"`

**EDIT**:

To enable the snapins, use:

```
Add-PSSnapin SqlServerProviderSnapin
Add-PSSnapin SqlServerCmdletSnapin
```

Comment: OK Noob time. I've spent the last half hour or so looking for where to download/add Invoke-SQL. (I also did that the other night and wasn't able to find it). I foolishly thought it would in the "Microsoft Windows PowerShell Extensions for SQL Server" off the SQL Feature Pack page. But after installing it I was no where closer. LOL

Comment: You have to install the packages. I'll add a note for that in the answer.

Comment: Ohh you know I tried that. Nada.. :) Gonna reboot maybe, just maybe its required and I missed that.

Comment: F'it I'm going to install the full blown management tools. I thought I could get away with traveling light but apparently not. *shrug*

Comment: Alright I got it! I installed the management tools then ran Add-PSSnapin SqlServerCmdletSnapin100
Add-PSSnapin SqlServerProviderSnapin100

Comment: @Aaron - Great news, post again if you have other questions/issues.  I have used those cmdlets a lot and they are super useful.